# Detect redirect with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, redirect

Does anyone know if it is possible to check when a page loads if the visitor was redirected to that page automatically, by using only JavaScript?

I do not want to redirect the visitor. I have in mind something similar to what this Chrome plugin is offering: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/redirect-path/aomidfkchockcldhbkggjokdkkebmdll?hl=en

Comment: Not sure how this is possible but have a look at `document.referrer;`

Comment: Thanks for the answer Aamir, but unfortunately document.referrer is not working. I have already checked this.

Comment: Goto this page directly http://jsfiddle.net/QqL76/show/ and you will see an empty alert. Open http://jsfiddle.net/Sa6hm/show/ and than click the link which will take you to the page (first link) and this time you will see from where this page is referred.

Comment: This is only working when you are using a direct link to send traffic. I want to get the referrer when using a 301 or 302 redirect